# Delta Logic implementation using SnapLogic with Azure Blob

Tags: snaplogic

Is there any snap available in SnapLogic to do following

1. Connect with snowflake and get data by SELECT *  FROM VIEW
2. Connect with Azure Blob Storage and get the data from csv file : FILENAME_YYYYMMDD.csv
3. Take only those data which are available in 1 but NOT available in 2 and write this delta back to Azure Blob Storage : FILENAME_YYYYMMDD.csv

Is In-Memory Look-Up useful for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `In-Memory Lookup` snap is used for cases where you need to look up the value corresponding to the value in a certain field of the incoming records. For example, say you want to look up a country name against the country ISO code. This snap generally fetches the lookup table once and stores it in memory. Then it uses this stored lookup table to provide data corresponding to the incoming records.

In your case, you have to use the `Join` snap and configure it to an inner join.